# Codename One - Socket closed when device is in standby

Tags: ios, sockets, codenameone

I'm developing an iOS app, using Codename One. I extended the SocketConnection class, in order to receive data from a server.

I tested the app on an iPhone 7s (iOS version 11.2.5 15D60) and it works fine. When I press the home button, the app suspends, but it keeps the connection with the socket server. But when the device goes into standby mode, the socket connection is closed.

Is it possible to avoid this behaviour, in order to keep the socket connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No and that's a good thing.

Long answer: When an app is suspended in iOS if it uses too much resources the OS kills the app to conserve battery life. Apple does allow some apps in some cases to perform tasks in the background but even then it's under heavy restrictions that are hard to follow and change frequently.

Generally you would define a background behavior that allows you to do something in the background. E.g. in this post we discuss [background fetch](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/background-fetch.html) which allows you to keep polling a server when we are in the background. It might not work with sockets.

The "right thing" in terms of iOS would be suspending your connection when in the background and using push notification to notify the user of a potential update.

Comment: I tried to implement a background behaviour, by means of BackgroundFetch. Unfortunately, my iPhone 7s does not support it (Display.getInstance().isBackgroundFetchSupported() returns false). What can I do? Is push notification the only way?

Comment: It could be because of missing XCode 9.x declarative permissions. It should work for iOS so this could be a regression. Please file a bug and we'll check if there is a missing permission here.